# Raspberry Pi Zero WH headless setup USB keeps disconnecting/connecting

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi-os, headless, setup

I'm new to this and sorry if this is a stupid question... I have a Raspberry Pi Zero WH and since I don't have a Mini-Hdmi cable I must setup it via USB. I've installed the Raspberry Pi OS on a SD card and plugged it in the Raspberry Pi WH but when I connect it to my PC over USB I keep hearing the windows sound for connecting and disconnecting a device over and over again (I already waited like 20 minutes or so). I also tried to change the USB port but that didn't make a difference. I also tried using a xBox controller and it's working perfectly fine. I also can not use the headless setup over wifi because I have to enable internet/wifi access for each Mac address in my router and I don't know how I can find out the Mac address of my raspberry pi without connecting to it first.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: first thing that comes to mind is to temporarily disable MAC filtering on your router ... second thing that comes to mind is a faulty cable ... third thing that comes to mind is windows drivers for the pi zero, or perhaps you haven't set the pi zero up correctly to work through USB (gadget mode I believe)

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately it's not my router and I can't disable MAC filtering (I'm living in a student residence). I found out about the driver issues on windows 10 so thank you for that! I will try to install that when I'm back home. I also might have found a way to connect to my wifi without enabling the MAC address first but I need to test that first. Again, thank you for leading me to the right direction

Answer (score 0):

It is quite difficult to setup Raspberry Pi OS headlessly as you need to specify user & password.
The Pi Zero (is it a Pi Zero W?) is even harder as it has no networking.

The Raspberry Pi Imager tool allows you to preconfigure an image with a user account (but I won't pretend it is easy)

See https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-bullseye-update-april-2022/
for detail

Comment: Thank you and sorry, it is a raspberry pi zero wh, I edited my question accordingly. The Raspberry Pi Imager tool is the tool I used to install the OS on the SD card and set the login information, ssh, etc.